# How to call data stored in a CSV/TEXT file format to range

Tags: vba

Good day,

I am struggling to proceed further from this, so with some research, I managed to this point and now i am stuck.

I need assistance to load the data into EXCEL as a datatable.

Here is my code.

```
    Sub MDM_API_CALL()

    Dim hReq As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim strUrl As String
        strUrl = "url to request bearer token"
    Set hReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
        With hReq
            .Open "POST", strUrl, False
            .Send
        End With

    Dim response As String
        response = hReq.responseText
        authKey = Mid(response, 11, Len(Mid(response, 11, Len(response) - 12)))

        strUrl = "url that requests the data in CSV format"
    Set hReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        With hReq
            .Open "GET", strUrl, False
            .SetRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer " & authKey
            .Send
        End With

        response = hReq.responseText

        ws.Range("A1").Value = response

    End Sub
```

After the code, the data is saved in cell A1 and my data is cropped due to the cell limit.

Thank you

Comment: Write `response` to a temp file, then open that file in excel using `Workbook.open("temp.csv")`

Comment: But how would you do it, because then i can just write it into cell A1 in this sheet?

Comment: If you save it to file and open it in excel then it will be parsed to rows/columns and not all jammed into one cell